# How can i use temporary tables in XE7, just like we use on delphi 2010 with component ttable

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I am trying to delelope system in XE7, and i needed to know how to use the temporary tables, like we use on delphi 10 with the component ttable.

for eg. this is done in delphi 2010.. 
i need to work on temporary table in delphi xe7.

please help me

```
if FileExists(gs_temppath + '\Findings.db') then
 begin
with Table_Findings do
begin
  Close;
  DatabaseName := gs_temppath;
  TableName := 'Findings.db';
  DeleteTable;
end;
 end;
with Table_Findings do
begin
   Close;
  DatabaseName := gs_temppath;
  TableName := 'Findings.db';
  TableType := ttDefault;
  FieldDefs.Clear;
  FieldDefs.Add('TestNameID', ftInteger);
  FieldDefs.Add('TestID', ftInteger);
  FieldDefs.Add('TestHead', ftString, 64);
  FieldDefs.Add('Test', ftString, 64);
  FieldDefs.Add('Finding', ftString, 255);
  FieldDefs.Add('Range', ftString, 250);
  FieldDefs.Add('Unit', ftString, 32);
  FieldDefs.Add('Extra', ftString, 100);
   FieldDefs.Add('ExtraFinding', ftString, 100);
  FieldDefs.Add('SampleNo', ftString, 32);
  FieldDefs.Add('Flag', ftString, 3);
  FieldDefs.Add('IsSubjective', ftString, 1);
  FieldDefs.Add('IsHeading', ftString, 1);
  FieldDefs.Add('CptCode', ftString, 100);
  CreateTable;
end;
```

Comment: You're going to need to be much more specific with your question if you want us to help. You may want to read [ask] and then come back to [edit] your post to make it more clear.

Comment: FireDAC with comes with Delphi XE7 have a TFDMemTable that you can use like a table in memory.

Comment: The answer to this q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932517/how-to-work-on-tfdtablefiredac-in-delphi-xe7 shows how to load an FDMemTable with a copy of an FDQuery's data.  If that doesn't answer your q, I suggest you post a new q explaining exactly what you've tried and the problem you are having with it.