# How to work on TFDTable(FireDAC) in Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi

can some body provide help me to use TFDTable.FireDac is completely new for me. I have used TTable in delphi 2010 for memory database. So i would like to use TFDTable in xe7 for temporary hold.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a coding service...

Comment: You could start here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Browsing_Tables_(FireDAC)

Comment: I found this just by googling "delphi tfdtable example". Couldn't you do this yourself?

Comment: Reading [ask] you should recognize that your question is not valid on [so]. So I voted to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to read up on FireDAC generally if you are completely unfamiliar with it, and look at the examples that come with recent versions of Delphi.

But if you just want to know how to copy data from a FireDAC dataset that's connected to a database to an in-memory table, you can do it very simply, like this:

```
procedure TForm1.btnCopyToMemTableClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDMemTable1.Data := FDQuery1.Data;
  FDQuery1.Close;  //  don't need it open any more
end;
```

Here, FDQuery1 is a TFDQuery, which is similar to a TQuery, in that it has a SQL TStrings property to allow you to specify what Sql query to execute to retrieve the data.

Comment: i want to add temporary table like this      with FDTable1 do
     begin

          TableName :='Test.db';
          IndexFieldNames := 'CustNo';
          //FieldDefs.Add('Testid',ftInteger);
          Open;
     end;